# I'm not myself since I stopped smoking

Tags: tense

This is a quote from "Annie Hall"

> I'm not myself since I stopped smoking.

Shouldn't present perfect be used here?

> I haven't been myself since I stopped smoking

Is it because **since** works as **because** here?

> I'm not myself because I stopped smoking

or is it just incorrect and present perfect is the right tense here?

Comment: Your logic is very good, but this is one of those funny situations in English where grammar rules can trick you. The original quote is exactly how I would say it as a native speaker though.

Answer (score 3):

Swan's *Practical English Usage* has this to say on the matter:

> However *[as opposed to Present Perfect]*, present and past tenses are occasionally found, especially in sentences about changes.
>
> ‘Since last Saturday I can’t stop thinking about you.’
>
> ‘You’re looking much better since your operation’

To me personally, using Simple Present emphasizes the causal link between current state and a past event, while Present Perfect is more about establishing the time at which it started.

So your sentence is correct, although note that *since* here is not fully interchangeable with *because* - a sentence like:

> I'm not myself because I stopped smoking.

does not imply that you not being yourself started right when you gave up smoking, while using *since* in this context does.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about it. Do you think I can use those tenses interchangeably? Like, "you're not yourself lately" or "you haven't been yourself lately"? And is it correct only in informal speech, or can I use it in formal as well?

Comment: @XDeath I'd use the Simple Present form if I wanted to relate to something that's happening at the moment ("You're drinking on the job again? You're not yourself lately!") and Present Perfect if it's been this way for a while ("For a week you've been bringing beer to work. You haven't been yourself lately.") In my opinion both are standard, neither overly formal nor overly informal.